# When creating an object, how can I have one property value set by 3 possible choices?

Tags: c#, list

This creates a new `SkyGlobe` object.

In the past, `OrbitYear` was determined by two different values, `firstYear` or `secondYear`.

But now I need to add another value, `testYear`, which would be 3 different choices.

However the ternary operator won't work here.

Is there another construct I can use?

```
select new SkyGlobe
{
    Id = sg.NetId,
    ProjectName = sg.projName,
    OrbitYear = previousYears.Contains(sg.ProjId) ? firstYear : secondYear,
    OrbiterId = previousYears.Contains(sg.ProjId) ? mainOrbit : secondaryOrbit,
    LeaderName = sg.OrbiterName
};
```

Comment: _"However the ternary operator won't work here."_ -  you can use 2 ternary operators. Or `switch`. Can you please add a [mre]? What logic determines which if the 3 choices to use?

Comment: Not 100%  clear but you can have a ternary within a ternary also

Comment: I would argue you should use a function to contain the logic that determines `OrbitYear` and call that, rather than confusing future readers of your code with nested ternaries, etc..

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh I see, so then just call the function inside where I create the new object?  that makes total sense, I am not sure why I didn't think of that!  thanks!

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, I just threw that out there for "possible" not "what I would do" here - perhaps even a private method that returns the proper value from whatever than new set of conditions require etc.

Comment: What exactly are the three conditions? Perhaps there is a simpler way?